# Can't change current time of play when clicking on an audio progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

I load a music track in my page, and the player works fine except that when I click on the progress bar to change the current time it doesn't work. This is my player:

```html
<audio controls style="width: 100%" id="player">
  <source id="player" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

The controls such as adjust volume, play and pause work fine, it's just I can't change the current time of play when I click on the progress bar neither when I drag its indicator.

The audio that I'm trying to play is stored in my external hard drive.

I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet and added a free sound clip - you can see that scanning through the playback seems to work fine. The issue is most likely that the server you're using to serve the file does not allow partial content requests. You will need to double check the server configuration.

Comment: Hi. The audio that I'm loading is stored in my external hard drive. How would I be able to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you mean you're using your local file system? I.e. `src="file://audio.mp3"` or `src="C:\audio.mp3"`?

Comment: My audio is inside the folder of my project and my project is in my external hard drive, therefore it'd be like src="file://audio.mp3"

Comment: You should retrieve the file from a server. If you're running on windows you can quite easily install IIS, otherwise XAMPP is also free

Comment: I'm using Laravel and my audio file is in the folder /public/music of my project. All of the audios get played but I can't seem to change their current time.

May you be a bit more specific on what I should do? Like, what should I do after installing IIS or XAMPP? I'm kinda newbie with this. Thank you so much